# OnPress doesn't work React Native - Android

Tags: react-native

I call a function using the onpress method in React Native. OnPress does not work on Android while this works smoothly on iOS. It works when I try onPress elsewhere, but when I click on the image, onPress does not work.

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

onBildirim() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("notification", {
      title: "notification"
    });
  }
<View style={styles.footerBody}>
<Image
        source={require('../images/footer.png')} 
        style={{
          width:screenWidth,
          height:110,
          bottom:0,
          position: 'absolute'}} 
        />

 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onBildirim()}> 
<Image
        source={require('../images/haberlerbutton2.png')} 
        style={{
          width:35,
          height:35,
           position: 'absolute',
                     top:30,
          left:20 }} 
        />
          </TouchableHighlight>
                              <Text style={{
          width:55,
          height:35,
           position: 'absolute',
                     top:65,
          left:20,
                        fontSize: 11,
              fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Light' }} >Haberler</Text>

 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onBildirim()}> 

        <Image
        source={require('../images/canlıyayın.png')} 
        style={{
          width:35,
          height:35,
          top:30,
           position: 'absolute',
          right:20 }} 
        />
          </TouchableHighlight>
}
```

Comment: try touchableOpacity for Android maybe.

Comment: Don't work touchableOpacity

Comment: did you try adding higher z index for touchable opacity style? Try that and also add background color to see if it is covered

Answer (score 0):

**Main Issue Is  position: 'absolute', Image**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity, Text
} from 'react-native';
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

onBildirim() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("notification", {
      title: "notification"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      
        
        
        
        Hacker
        
           this.onBildirim()}>
            
          
           this.onBildirim()}>

```
        <Image
          source={require('../Images/hacker.jpg')}
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            marginHorizontal:20
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  </View>
);
```

}
}